# Xcode only picking up "AppIcon" as named variable in UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage

I'm currently trying to set icons for `tabBarItem`, but when I do the following code:

```
Main.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "List")
```

it doesn't work. It only finds the "AppIcon" iconset in `Assets.xcassets`, not the other icons.

Have anyone experienced this before and if so how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing image files, clean build folder and then add it again?
You can also check following link, it might help:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69206